# Deja-dup (backup tool) failing to backup

Tags: backup, deja-dup

Running Ubuntu 14.04, using deja-dup (default duplicity-Ubuntu) as backup tool.
It always worked till a couple of days ago.
When backup starts to run now it reports an error:

> Backup Failed

```
Failed to read /home/marc/.cache/deja-dup/tmp/duplicity-t863_c-tempdir/mktemp-1mlXkQ-1: (<type 'exceptions.IOError'>, IOError('CRC check failed 0x967502e6 != 0x41060bb5L',), <traceback object at 0x7f5a6f9fc8c0>)
```

The referred cache and tmp folders are empty (also no hidden files).
Deleting the folder deja-dup under the cache results in a regeneration and the same error message (folders are always empty).

Comment: this is a [bug#875676 
Backing up fails with 'IOError CRC check failed'.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/875676)

Comment: Yes, it seems a bug! It is already reported in 2010 (https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/676767) and then market as solved (clean cache action). but then again reported as bug in 2011 (your link). Since then nothing has been done!.  Time to use another, better, tool?

Comment: Report again as bug?